# How to separate NSArray values?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

NSArray has 3 values

```
@[@"addd:etyrhetwrwr", @"fdfdd:jjjjhhhh", @"fsuy:jjhwgggggg"]
```

And I want to put this array into the UILabel with word wrap.
So when I run, it should show like this in label.

```
addd:etyrhetwrwr
fdfdd:jjjjhhhh
fsuy:jjhwgggggg
```

But I can't separate this NSArray. How can I do that?

Comment: add some snippet what you have done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"addd:etyrhetwrwr", @"fdfdd:jjjjhhhh", @"fsuy:jjhwgggggg"];
NSString *labelString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then use the labelString to set your label `text` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
NSArray *yourArray = @[@"addd:etyrhetwrwr", @"fdfdd:jjjjhhhh", @"fsuy:jjhwgggggg"];
NSString *string = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
[yourLabel setText:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `NSArray` in UILabel by

```
NSArray myArr = @[@"addd:etyrhetwrwr", @"fdfdd:jjjjhhhh", @"fsuy:jjhwgggggg"];
NSString strLabel = [myArr string:@"\n"];
```

Comment: you could have at least changed the variable names before pasting my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"adad",@"fgfdgdfg",@"sddgfs", nil];
    NSMutableString *strFinalData = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {
        [strFinalData appendFormat:@"%@ ",[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Final String: %@",strFinalData);
```

Now set `yourLabel.text = strFinalData;`